# Mod rewrite with 3 parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I did tons of methods to figure out how to make this mod rewrite but O was completly unsuccessful.

I want a .htaccess code that rewrite in the following method:

- `/apple/upcoming/2` → `/handler.php?topic=apple&orderby=upcoming&page=2`

This is easy to do, but the problem is that all parameters are not required so the link has different levels of parameters each time like this:

- `/apple/popular/2` → `/handler.php?topic=apple&orderby=popular&page=2`
- `/apple/2` → `/handler.php?topic=apple&orderby=&page=2`
- `/all/popular/2` → `/handler.php?topic=all&orderby=popular&page=2`
- `/apple/upcoming/` → `/handler.php?topic=apple&orderby=upcoming&page=`

So briefly, the URL has 3 optional parameters in one static order: (topic) (orderby) (page)

Note: the ORDERBY parameter can be "popular" or "upcoming" or nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest redirecting everything after domain name(/apple/upcoming/2) to index.php and from there use php to parse url and call appropriate function.

Comment: +1 you cannot use mod rewrite to rewrite a url without a query.

Comment: Any modrewrite code to redirect everything after domain name to handler.php?everything=XXXX ? thanks

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal: That’s just plain wrong. You sure can use mod_rewrite to rewrite every request without touching the query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule     ^([0-9]*)/?$ handler.php?topic=&orderby=&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(upcoming|popular)/([0-9]*)/?$ handler.php?topic=&orderby=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^([^/]*)/([0-9]*)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^([^/]*)/(upcoming|popular)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=$2&page= [L]
RewriteRule     ^([^/]*)/(upcoming|popular)/([0-9]*)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

You should simply declare rewrites in preferred order.

Answer (score 0):

For the cases you provided above there rules should work:

```
RewriteRule     ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=$2&page= [L]
RewriteRule     ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ handler.php?topic=$1&orderby=$2&page=$3 [L]
```